# Get server URL in django docker

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am running Django project in docker. I have 3 docker container.

1. For Django App
2. For Postgres
3. For Nginx

My `docker-compose.yml` file is as follow

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    container_name: tts-db
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=tts
    expose:
      - "5432"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: tts-nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/site-enabled:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web

  web:
    build: .
    container_name: tts-app
    environment:
      - DATABASE=db
      - DEBUG=False
      - STATICFILES_STORAGE=whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage
    depends_on:
      - db
    expose:
      - "8888"
    entrypoint: ./entry_point.sh
    command: gunicorn urdu_tts.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8888
    restart: always
```

In my django app, I need to access host address. I used `request.get_host()` which works in localhost. When I run this in Docker, I get url like `http://web/media/voice/voice.wav`. My nginx configuration is as follow.

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8888;
}

server {

    location ^/static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/;
    }

    location ~ ^/media/?(.*)$ {
        try_files /media/$1 /mediafiles/$1 =404;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
        client_max_body_size 20m;
    }
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

How can I get server url in Docker?

Comment: Perhaps set an environment variable called SERVER_URL and access it in code through your settings?

Comment: In this case, I will have to set this every time I run this on any machine.

Comment: But your URL would remain the same regardless of which server you deploy your code to, I presume?

Comment: I have not deployed to any live server yet. And this will be an open source project as anyone can run it on their machine. Setting server url in environment variable will solve my issue but I want a dynamic solution.

Comment: Simply, you could add a `hostname` field in your compose file so that django will consume the hostname in a correct way. E.g. `hostname: yourserver.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using following configuration in Nginx configuration works for me.

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host; # Define host as http_host.
```

Now my nginx configuration looks like this:

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8888;
}

server {

    location ^/static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/;
    }

    location ~ ^/media/?(.*)$ {
        try_files /media/$1 /mediafiles/$1 =404;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
        client_max_body_size 20m;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol "";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl "";
    }
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

Comment: Just in case you wrote this is going to be an open source program: Not everybody uses Nginx, and this could change the story if you were deploying outside docker. Also, providing environment variables is usually the recommended way for production usages. So I'd suggest you to at least mention using an env var or any django-related configuration in the documentation of your product.

Comment: There can be many ways depending on the scenerios and system you are using. Here it is answered according to question asked.